How should I implement data access with jpa to meet Clean Architecture/DDD
For the last few days I'm searching any information about compatibility of JPA and Clean Architecture/DDD. I found next ideas for decoupling application from hibernate.

Do not use @ManyToMany or @OneToMany, or use it only with Eager fetching. Domain layer have Repository interface that operates domain entities - POJO and data layer have Repository implementation, that call jpaRepository and maps POJO to/from Hibernate Entity. This way honestly sounds like "let's use jpa, but forbid most of it features".

@Repository
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DemoRepositoryImpl implements DemoRepository {

    private final JpaDemoRepository jpaDemoRepository;
    private final DemoMapper demoMapper;

    @Override
    public Demo findById(UUID id) {
        // this one have eager fetching
        return demoMapper.toDomain(jpaDemoRepository.findById(id));
    }
}


To keep some sort of lazy fetching, make 2 methods in repository: one with lazy fetching and one custom for eager. May sounds better, but still crop JPA and custom eager method will use jpql for another entity, what violate rule, that repository only operate with it own entity.

@Repository
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DemoRepositoryImpl implements DemoRepository {

    private final JpaDemoRepository jpaDemoRepository;
    private final DemoMapper demoMapper;

    @Override
    public Demo findById(UUID id) {
        // this one will use lazy fetching, so some fields will be null
        return demoMapper.toDomain(jpaDemoRepository.findById(id));
    }

    @Override
    public Demo findByIdEager(UUID id) {
        // this one will use eager fetching, so all fields will be populated
        return demoMapper.toDomain(jpaDemoRepository.findByIdEager(id));
    }
}


Previous two is good, but crop jpa features. This one is about represent domain as interface and 2 realizations: POJO for mock and Hibernate Entity for real data access. This one is way more decoupled from hibernate. It violates Domain principles, but we can use all jpa features, and we can operate everything through domain interfaces:

public interface Demo{
    Long getId();
    String getName();
    String getSomeField();
    void setId(Long id);
    void setName(String name);
    void setSomeField(String someField);
} 

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "t_demo")
public class DemoEntity implements Demo{

    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String someField;
}

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface PersonRepository<T extends Demo> extends JpaRepository<T, Long> {
    
    public T findById(Long id);
}

@Repository
public interface JpaDemoRepository extends PersonRepository<DemoEntity> { 
    
}

Each of this implementation have its own pros and cons, and I want to hear somebody's opinion: do these implementations have rights to exist in real projects? Should I use them or just couple application to jpa?

The question misses the core point of what Clean Architecture tries to get you to do.
The main goal here is that the specific implementation details of your persistence technology are contained within the persistence layer, with the domain/application not being aware of it to any degree. At the end of the day, if I delete your repository implementation (i.e. class) and only see its interface, I should not be able to tell what kind of persistence mechanism you're using.

Domain layer have Repository interface that operates domain entities

Correct. Note that since the domain does not depend on anything, it does not depend on your persistence technology, which is why it is a "safe" type to use as part of the input/output in the repository interface.

This way honestly sounds like "let's use jpa, but forbid most of it features".

Disagree, but I understand where your observation comes from.
The issue here isn't that you're not allowed to use JPA features. The issue here is that Clean Architecture forces you to keep the interface clean, in the sense that it doesn't reveal the specific library your persistence layer may or may not be depending on.
The reason you're interpreting this as "not being allowed to use JPA features" has nothing to do with such features, but it has everything to do with using JPA features. You've not considered rolling your own implementation of this behavior, which is why your observation doesn't include this as an avenue, and why you feel like the only remaining option is to "not use the feature" at all.
If you want the concept of lazy loading and optionally fetchable navigational properties, then you have to introduce this concept to your domain layer. Since your domain layer (by its very design) does not depend on anything, this means you can't just use the lazy loading implementation from an existing library, you have to roll your own.
A more accurate rephrasing of your observation  would be "use jpa or not, the codebase doesn't care; but the interface must be built solely from domain features - so any back-and-forth interaction between the repo and another layer must be backed by a domain concept, not a third party library plugin."


To keep some sort of lazy fetching, make 2 methods in repository: one with lazy fetching and one custom for eager.


This is a viable example of what I mentioned before, i.e. how you can model your interface (and backing domain) to reflect the interaction you want.
One thing I suggest though is doing away with the "eager/lazy" naming and instead use something a bit more tech-agnostic, such as using a Person (only the person itself) vs PersonDetails (i.e. including related entities) distinction rather than referring to the method of loading (which is a persistence-specific mechanic).
This is mostly a naming refactor rather than a technical one, but the semantics matter here too as they themselves can also be the "leak" of persistence information outside of the persistence layer.

Should I use them or just couple application to jpa?

There is no objective right and wrong. I've written plenty of small tools that tightly couple to their persistence tech simply because they were small sandbox tools with a short lifespan. Based on the scope and lifespan of the application, there is always an upper ceiling as to how much effort you should be investing in the abstraction and clean separation of your codebase.
But if you tightly couple yourself to JPA, then you're throwing Clean Architecture out the window. Whether that is the right call for you or not, I can't judge, but I can point out that if you make this decision, I would suggest you stop trying to adhere to a principle that you can't adhere to anymore - because trying to do so would be a waste of effort (at best) or cause you to create a warped idea of what Clean Architecture is (at worst)

Either

Don't use attributes, (try persistence.xml ?)

Or

Map the 'entity' to a real, non attributed 'domain model' before exposing it outside the repository

Having the attributes on the domain model creates a reference from the domain layer out to whatever layer your ORM library is in and hence breaks CA.
Adding interfaces to your entities doesn't really help, if you try to persist an entity which doesn't have the attributes because its not defined in the repo layer it will fail unless you have a similar aforementioned mapping.
Of course you can just go 'meh' and just allow the attribute usages for ease of use. However, if you reuse the entities in an app which doesn't have the repo layer, its going to pull in that whole ORM lib for no reason.
